# How safe is returning a password from a function?

Tags: php, security

Is returning sensitive data like a password from a function safe, and what attack vectors exist?
(Personally, it is regarding PHP, but is a general question.)

```
function returnDBPass(){
    $pass="mydbpass";
    return $pass;
}
```

Comment: [Sharing your research helps everyone](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6559/why-is-research-important). Tell us what you've tried and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer. Also see [ask]

Comment: Why has this been down voted? "Tell us what you've tried and why it didn’t meet your needs" is not relevant to my question. I can not see any related questions and searching results in many hash related questions which is unrelated. If I was to give one hypothetical attack vector it would be a hacker somehow being able to execute arbitrary functions in my script, but I don't know how that attack vector can be created.

Comment: Why on earth would you ever need such a function?

Comment: @DanPichelman Abstraction, DRY, hypothetically.

function connectToDB(){$user=returnDBUser(); $pass=returnDBPass(); ...}